# Workaround for border-image IE 8 & IE 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I don't know if css is the best way to make this works... I have this image:

[image: form border]

and I want all of my form to be inside of it. I have this aspnet.mvc 4 site, so I have this on razor:

```
<div id="form">
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Foo", "Boo", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
      {
           //form here
      }
</div>
```

My layout:

```
<!-- container-->
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

CSS:

```
.main-content {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#form {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-horizontal {
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font: bold 14px sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-width: 150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url(../../images/Iphone.png) 25%;
}
```

I have the expected result on chrome but not on IE 8/7 (of course)

[image: top result on chrome]

[image: Bottom result on chrome]

Is there any workaround for this? What is the best approach?
PS: the form containt can grow up with some javascript, that's why I need to be "elastic".

@fordareh, I tryed your solution but it didn't work.
I tryed this before cutting the image on 3:

[image: top_image]

[image: middle image]

[image: bottom image]

My idea was to simple repeat that "middle image" on Y position, but on both sides.. and I couldn't do it...

:(

Comment: Just to be clear: there is no work-around for `border-image` on IE7/8. It you want to support IE7/8, you will need to use a different technique entirely. I suggest a good old fashioned background image. Or just drop support for IE7/8. (I assume you've been given this requirement by a client so you can't just make the decision to drop it for yourself, but please try talking to them about not supporting such obsolete browsers. I work with government clients and even they are upgrading away from IE8 now - there comes a point where even the most backward looking organisation can't resist progress)

Comment: I wish you were wrong Simba... but I work with a consulting company.. its pretty much unreal that I talk to my client like that... Because my client is my client's client. And they all work with old fashion browsers... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're going to have with this background image as a single image is that the glare on the face of the iPad prevents any part of it from repeating.  I've created a similar effect to what you might be looking for using the css and images in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fordareh/1jzgk34f/

The trick is to isolate the top and bottom corners so that they don't expand since that would distort them.  Then, you scale the middle slice so that it joins up nicely to the glare (with a filter hack that should work just fine in

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="form-horizontal">

      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Css:

```
.top {
  width: 535px; 
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTrcf.png') no-repeat;
  padding-top: 55px;
}

.bottom {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/65D0M.png') no-repeat bottom;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
}

.middle {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N1JX.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  overflow: auto;

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
  src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N1JX.png',
  sizingMethod='scale')\9;

  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
  src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N1JX.png',
  sizingMethod='scale')"\9;

}

.form-horizontal {
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 75px;
}
```

Images:

[image: Top]
[image: Middle]
[image: Bottom]

Alternatively, you could fix the height of .form-horizontal and set "overflow: auto" to simply force the form to scroll.

Comment: I edited the question with your solution... i'm sorry bud, it didn't work.. I tryed this once before :(

Comment: @MarllonNasser - I updated the jsfiddle with some more info -- I think the trouble you're having is that you're trying to use border-image and need to be using background-image(s): https://jsfiddle.net/fordareh/1jzgk34f/

Comment: the problem is IE 8/7... have you tested on these browsers? I still can't figure this out :(

Comment: @MarllonNasser - yes, tested IE7,8,11 and chrome/ff edge.  Are you sure that you're copying the code from the jsfiddle?  The filters are important for IE support as are the \9 characters for targeting IE8 and below.  Can you post a link to a live test?

Comment: yes i'm sure.. I just made some changes to work with local files.... I cant post any link..you have to be on company's network to access :(

Comment: well, I'm not sure what to tell you -- if you can get a live version up, I'll take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103214/discussion-between-fordareh-and-marllon-nasser).

Comment: I've made some changes (increase image's width) and Its working on IE 8... but not on IE 7... :(